# React-native: Export function using 'this' from other component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm actually having an issue in my React-native logic and I need your precious help !

I have my main component 'Main.js' and I want to import a function from 'Function.js' that should change the state of 'Main.js'...

But of course I don't have access to "Main.js"'s *this*.
So my question is:

How can I change the Main.js state from an exported function in Function.js ?

Here is the kind of code in Function.js

```
_function = () => {
   ... Getting MyState in AsyncStorage ...
   var MyState = ...;
   this.setState({ User: MyState })
}
```

And my Main.js

```
import { _function } from 'Function.js'
...
componentDidMount(){
   this._function()
}
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the instance a parameter of the function:

```
export const _function = (main) => {
   // ... Getting MyState in AsyncStorage ...
   var MyState = …
   main.setState({ User: MyState })
};
```

```
import { _function } from 'Function.js'
…
  componentDidMount(){
    _function(this)
  }
…
```

Or don't use an arrow function so that you can actually use it as a method:

```
export function _function() {
   // ... Getting MyState in AsyncStorage ...
   var MyState = …
   this.setState({ User: MyState })
};
```

```
import { _function } from 'Function.js'
…
  componentDidMount(){
    _function.call(this)
  }
…
```

You could even install it as a real method:

```
import { _function } from 'Function.js'
class Main {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.method();
  }
}
Main.prototype.method = _function;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function in your `_function` parameters.

In main.js, you would have a function

```
setUser = (User) => {
  this.setState({user});
}
```

Then you call `_function` and pass `setUser` as a parameter.

```
componentDidMount(){
  _function(this.setUser)
}
```

In Function.js, you edit your function to receive the function and call it.

```
_function = (setUser) => {
 ... Getting MyState in AsyncStorage ...
 var MyState = ...;
 setUser(MyState);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Looks great too !